# Auto inizialize List and Dictionary autoproperty in a class

Tags: c#, properties

I've got a class with this property:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> LoggedProperties { get; set; }
```

I want to automatically initialize it. Without using the contructor.

The reason is that I think there is no pro in having the default value for it to null

I mean that if I access to a class member (static or after instantiating the class) I don't want to get null reference exception. It has no sense for me.. I want to avoid the default value for object is null.

Is there any compact way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing automatic properties is not supported by the current version of C#.

It is one of the highly requested features on [VisualStudio C# UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2163145-allow-default-values-on-automatic-properties). There's a chance it'll be implemented in C# 6, because developers decided to add many tiny syntactic features in this release. If you want the feature to be implemented, you can vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private Dictionary<int,string>  m_LoggedProperties = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public Dictionary<int,string> LoggedProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return m_LoggedProperties;
        }
        set
        {
            m_LoggedProperties = value;
        }
    }
```

Although what do you mean by `without using the constructor`? There's no way to initialize member of uninitialized object. It's just a syntactic sugar - dictionary member will still be initialized on the constructor invocation.

Comment: I mean that if I access to a class member (static or after instantiating the class) I don't want to get null reference exception.  It has no sense for me.. I want to avoid the default value for object is null.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use auto properties I think.

Comment: @Sam And how's my solution not working for you? I do understand what do you want, but it's undoable because the class object itself HAS TO BE initialized - constructor cannot be ommited, so it doesn't matter where do you define your default value - it'll be initialized the same way.

Comment: @Tarec: the constructor, for sure, is called. But I don't want to have to remember to initialize every Proprerty from the constructor. I think it is only leading to unuseful null reference exception. I would like somethink as Athari is saying: syntactic sugar for avoiding the need to initialize autoproperty in the constructor.

Comment: @Sam I'm sorry, but did you even read my answer? It's commonly used method for defining default auto-initializable properties. If MS'll ever introduce a syntactic sugar for it, it'll have this method beneath. Syntactic sugar is only a term of wrapping something in a simple form - it does not provide any new functionality itself.

Comment: @Tarec: yes, I like your answer. I upvoted it. And also upvoted both of your comment.

Comment: @Sam I'm sorry, I thought you did not find it helpfull, however I do understand that it's more of a workaround, than a real answer.

Comment: @Tarec: yes, I like it, but I also hope Microsoft will introduce also Syntactic sugar for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Only way is change AutoProperty to standard property like:

```
    private Dictionary _LoggedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> LoggedProperties 
    { 
       get { return _LoggedProperties; } 
       set { this._LoggedProperties = value; } 
    }
```

If you want initialize your property when it's first used, you can do following:

```
       get {
             if (_LoggedProperties == null)
             {
                _LoggedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
             }
             return _LoggedProperties;
           }
```